# Python setuptools integration with pip, setup_require vs pip install

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, setuptools, setup.py

I have `setup.py` and `requirements.txt` files, at the req file i put all the packages i need for my package and i'm using it at the `install_requires=read_from_file()` option.

Now i have 2 more options in use at my `setup.py`:

```
setup_requires=['rst2pdf', 'pytest', 'sphinx==1.3.1', 'sphinx-epytext'],
tests_require=['pytest-cov', 'pytest-xdist', 'pytest-pep8', 'pytest-cache'],
```

`setup_requires` for packages i need at the setup phase, and `test_require` for testing phase.

I have a problem (only with) installing `rst2pdf` which results with(trace-back just for showing):

```
distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Setup script exited with error: Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat). Get it from http://aka.ms/vcpython27
```

The issue is that if i'm using `pip install rst2pdf` it works fine and installs the package with all it's dependencies.

Since i don't want to add the package to the req file my question is:

Whats the diffrence between calling `pip install <package>` vs using `setup_requires=['package]` at my `setup.py`? and how can make them behave the same?

**my work-space:** python 2.7, windows 7, pip 1.5.6, setuptools 15.2